# Cannot verify user credentials Python + Flask

Tags: python, flask

I've been trying for way too long to get the email and the password of a user. I'm a (huge) beginner and I think my understanding of tutorials is no longer enough... This is what I (tried to) have:

```
# all the imports
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
    abort, render_template, flash, send_from_directory
from contextlib import closing

# configuration

DATABASE = '/tmp/database.db'
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'hey'
USERNAME = 'admin@admin.com'
PASSWORD = 'default'

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# set the project root directory as the static folder, you can set others.

# app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['inputEmail'] != app.config['USERNAME']:
            error = 'Invalid username'
        elif request.POST['inputPassword'] != app.config['PASSWORD']:
            error = 'Invalid password'
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return redirect(url_for('/app'))

    return render_template('index.html', error=error)
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestion or comments, I would really appreciate that.

Have a nice day,
John

Comment: What do you mean "Cannot verify user credentials ", could you explain more?

Comment: With my present code no matter what it seems like nothing happens... I just want to verify that the values the user enter correspond to the configuration values and if yes, go to page /app. Here is my html:

                  <input type="email" class="form-control floating-label" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
          
             
                  <input type="password" class="form-control floating-label" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">

Comment: Should be `request.form` instead of `request.POST`?

Comment: Thanks lord63.j. I did the change and receive "GET /? HTTP/1.1" 200 - after trying to enter credentials. It just seems like correct or wrong, nothing happens on the page

Comment: the `url_for` is not right in your code, use the endpoint, not `/app`.

Comment: I mean, for example, `@app.route('/app') def admin():pass`, then you should use `redirect(url_for('admin'))`.

Comment: That did work! Thanks a lot lod63 for your time and fast response!

Comment: My pleasure :) Add the comments as the final answer. Have a look and you may choose it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post my comments as the final answer:

1. problem one:

the way we get the form data is via `request.form` not `request.POST`.

2. problem two:

when you redirect to another page, it should be `url_for('endpoint')`, not `url_for('/app')`. For exmaple:

```
@app.route('/app')
def admin():
    pass
```

then the redirect should be: `redirect(url_for('admin'))`.